# Is a liaison before "au" also forbidden?

Tags: liaisons

There are some forbidden French liaison rules:

> Before & After Full Names: Albert est
>   After et: et une de plus
>   Before onze: il y avait onze
>   Before oui: on a dit “oui”
>   After Plural Nouns: les arbres en fleurs
>   Before the letter a: Je vais à Paris
>   After Singular Nouns: la maison est
>   Before H aspiré: en haut

Like for "onze" and "oui", is a liaison before "au" also forbidden?

Comment: Where did you get those rules from? Liaisons after plural nouns, before the letter *a* are **not forbidden**. Liaison before *au* is not among the forbidden liaisons either. *Les arbres‿  en fleurs,  je vais‿ à la gare, je vais‿ au marché*, are optional liaisons. For more [read this article on wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais).

Comment: /ʒəvɛz‿aʁijo dəʒanɛʁo/ ;-)

Comment: I find that [this webpage](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/liaison.html) does a great job explaining which _liaisons_ are mandatory and which are frowned upon or forbidden. _Liaisons_ are not forbidden after plural nouns or before the letter _a_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have indicated in comments, many of the rules you cite are wrong. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(French)) is reliable.

> Before & After Full Names: Albert est
>   After et: et une de plus

These two are correct.

> Before onze: il y avait onze

This is correct, but I would generalize the rule to “no liaison before numerals”. For example “*cent un*” is pronounced [sɑ̃.œ̃] (no liaison). Contrast the use of *un* as a common noun: “*les uns et les autres*” (“the ones and the others”) [le.z‿œ̃.e.le.z‿otʁ].

> After Singular Nouns: la maison est

This is correct. *Une liaison interdite, des liaisons (-z-) autorisées.*

> Before oui: on a dit “oui”
>   Before H aspiré: en haut

That's technically correct, but a more useful way to think about these words is to consider that they do not start with a vowel sound: they start with a silent consonant (the “H aspiré”). For example the definite article is not elided: “*l**e** oui et le non”, “l**e** haut”. If the word doesn't start with a vowel, there's no opportunity for a liaison.

> <s>After Plural Nouns: les arbres en fleurs</s>
>   <s>Before the letter a: Je vais à Paris</s>

These are completely wrong. In both cases, the liaison is optional. I'd do it in formal speech or in poetry, and omit it in everyday speech. There's no difference between *à* and *au* in this respect: “je vais au travail” has an optional liaison.